# Adding an @property in an NSObject as a pointer to an @property in another NSObject

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a 1v1 game that I am updating to 3 players (eventually 4) and I am running into an issue with player tracking when the user is playing against 2 computer players.

I have a Game NSObject that handles all of the major code for the gameplay, and also controls the actions of the computer players. In the past, I have been good with 2 properties in Game.h (User and Opponent), and now I have 3 (User, Opponent, Opponent2). Declared like the following:

```
@property (retain) Player *user;
```

The problem comes in when I need to use a method that controls computer player actions. As an example, when the computer player needs to bid, it must know the bids and some other info about it's opponents. A snippet of the old code is:

```
- (void)computerBiddingObjects {
        // ... other stuff
    if (_opponentPoints == 110 && _userPoints >= 90 && _userDidBid != YES) {
          bid = bidTwenty;
    } else if (_opponentPoints == 115 && _userPoints >= 90 && _userDidBid != YES) {
          bid = bidTwentyFive;
    }
        // ... other stuff
}
```

In order to get information for the opposing players, a thought I had was to add 2 new properties to Player.h in order to track each player's opponents (opponent1 and opponent2). My question is, if I set the properties for each Player as in:

```
_opponent.opponent = _user;
_opponent.opponent2 = _opponent2;
```

Can I refer to them and/or set their individual properties in both contexts? Would these statements be equivalent given the above:

```
_opponent.opponent.didBid = YES;
_user.didBid = YES;
```

Also, could I access the Player objects properties like this new version of the bidding code snippet?

```
- (void)computerBiddingObjectsForOpponent:(Player *)opponent {
        // ... other stuff
    if (opponent.points == 110 && self.currentBid < bidTwenty && ((opponent.opponent1.points >= 90 && opponent.opponent1.didBid != YES) || (opponent.opponent2.points >= 90 && opponent.opponent2.didBid != YES))) {
          bid = bidTwenty;
    } else if (opponent.points == 115 && self.currentBid < bidTwentyFive && ((opponent.opponent1.points >= 90 && opponent.opponent1.didBid != YES) || (opponent.opponent2.points >= 90 && opponent.opponent2.didBid != YES))) {
          bid = bidTwentyFive;
    }
        // ... other stuff
    opponent.bid = bid.
}
```

Am I way off base/off track? Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed equivalent.

But ...

The `didBid` will be set by the other players as well (as they hold the same reference to that player, overwriting what each player has set.

You are creating a retain cycle you might need to break manually (or set the opponents properties as `weak`).

It might be best if each player will keep a "Strategy" object for each opponent, and that strategy will have a reference to the player. This way, each player may have different strategy against any other player.

Comment: So, just instead of having the opponent objects in the Player objects themselves, I would have them in a Stategy object?

Comment: You have strategic information on each player (the player reference is only for identification and access to player current state [read only]). (`Player` has `strategies`(per opponent) each of which has reference to another `Player` and internal `Strategy` information regarding that player)